# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type [Working on structs]

Tags: c, pointers, types

I have declared:

```
#include stdio.h

#include stdlib.h

#include string.h

#include dictionary.h

int main( int argc, char ** argv ){

    char * dictionary_name = DEFAULT_DICTIONARY;
    dictionary_t dictionary;
    dictionary->entries = 1;
    if ( dictionary == NULL){
        printf("NULL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
src/main.c: In function ‘main’:
src/main.c:40:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct dictionary_s’
dictionary->entries = 1;
```

**In dictionary.c:**

```
#include dictionary.h

struct dictionary_s{

    char * name;
    llist_t content;
    int entries;
};
```

**In header (dictionary.h):**

```
typedef struct dictionary_s* dictionary_t;
```

It's my first time asking a question in here, so, please forgive me if I'm missing something important.

Comment: kind of <O/T>, but any particular reason for using a pointer to `struct dictionary_s` rather than simply an object? Even when you get this problem resolved, you'll need to allocate space for a dictionary object before you can `dictionary->entries = 1;`, as dereferencing a pointer that points to nothing is undefined behavior. I'd just do `struct dictionary_s dictionary; dictionary.entries = 1; ...`

Comment: Theres more to this code, I just showed what gives an error and everything that is relevant to it.

Answer (score 0):

The file `dictionary.h` only contains the name of the type `struct dictionary_s`, so that is all that is visible to your `main` function.  This means it doesn't know what the structure contains.

You need to move the definition of `struct dictionary_s` into the header file.  That way it can be used from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the definition of the `struct` in the header file, not in the `dictionary.c`-file; otherwise, its components are not known outside of `dictionary.c`.

So your `dictionary.h` should look as follows:

```
struct dictionary_s{

    char * name;
    llist_t content;
    int entries;
};

typedef struct dictionary_s* dictionary_t;
```

Your file `dictionary.c` is probably obsolete then.